# Can't login with user ID and password i created with rest API

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, express, authentication

**Get an error while trying to log in with the username and password I created with rest API but I can log in with the same username and password via postman**

**Error**

node:internal/errors:464
ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:576:11)    at ServerResponse.header (D:\Current Work\Full Stack Ecom\api\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:794:10)
at ServerResponse.send (D:\Current Work\Full Stack Ecom\api\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:174:12)
at ServerResponse.json (D:\Current Work\Full Stack Ecom\api\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:278:15)
at D:\Current Work\Full Stack Ecom\api\routes\auth.js:48:25
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}

**This is what I get while I check the request**

**I get this in HEADERS**

Request URL: http://localhost:5000/api/auth/login
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 401 Unauthorized
Remote Address: [::1]:5000
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

And this in Responses
"Wrong Credentials!"

[Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZ85b.png)
[Responsses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrQ6r.png)

**This is my login route**

```
router.post("/login", async (req,res)=>{
try{
    const user = await User.findOne({username: req.body.username});
    !user && res.status(401).json("Wrong Credentials!")
    const hashedPassword = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
        user.password, 
        process.env.PASS_SEC
        );
    const OriginalPassword = hashedPassword.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
    OriginalPassword !==req.body.password &&
    res.status(401).json("Wrong Credentials!");

    const accessToken = jwt.sign({
        id:user._id,
        isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
    },process.env.JWT_SEC,{expiresIn:"3d"}
    );

    const {password, ...others} = user._doc;

    res.status(200).json({...others, accessToken});
}catch(err){
    res.status(500).json(err)
}});
```

**This is my request methode**

```
import axios from "axios";
const BASE_URL = "http://localhost:5000/api/";
const TOKEN = "TOKEN";
export const publicRequest = axios.create({
    baseURL: BASE_URL,
});
export const userRequest = axios.create({
    baseURL: BASE_URL,
    header: {token: `Bearer ${TOKEN}`}
})
```

**This is user redux**

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState: {
    currentUser: null,
    isFeteching: false,
    error: false
  },
  reducers: {
    loginStart:(state)=>{
      state.isFeteching=true
    },
    loginSucess:(state,action)=>{
      state.isFeteching=false;
      state.currentUser=action.payload
    },
    loginFailour:(state)=>{
      state.isFeteching=false;
      state.error=true;
    },
    },
  });

export const { loginStart,loginSucess,loginFailour } = userSlice.actions;
export default userSlice.reducer;
```

**This is my API call**

```
import { loginFailour,loginStart,loginSucess } from "./userRedux";
import {publicRequest} from "../requestMethods";

export const login= async (dispatch, user)=>{
    dispatch(loginStart());
    try {
        const res = await publicRequest.post("auth/login", user);
        dispatch(loginSucess(res.data));
    } catch (err) {
        dispatch(loginFailour());
    }
};
```

**This is my login page**

```
const Login = () => { 
    const[userName,setUsername] = useState("");
    const[password,setPassword] = useState("");
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const handleClick = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault()
        login(dispatch,{userName,password})
    }
  return (   
  <Container>
    <Wrapper>
        <Title>SIGN IN</Title>
        <Form>
            <Input placeholder="username" 
            onChange={(e)=>setUsername(e.target.value)}/>
            <Input placeholder="password"
            type="password"
            onChange={(e)=>setPassword(e.target.value)}
            />
            <Button onClick={handleClick}>LOGIN</Button>
            <Link>FORGET PASSWORD</Link>
            <Link>CREATE A NEW ACCOUNT</Link>
        </Form>
    </Wrapper>
</Container>
  )
}
```

**I'm stuck here please help me to solve this error**

Answer (score 0):

Уou do not interrupt the execution of the function when send responce

```
router.post("/login", async (req,res)=>{
  try{
      const user = await User.findOne({username: req.body.username});
      if (!user) {
        return res.status(401).json("Wrong Credentials!")
      }
      const hashedPassword = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
          user.password, 
          process.env.PASS_SEC
          );
      const OriginalPassword = hashedPassword.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
      if (OriginalPassword !==req.body.password) {
        return res.status(401).json("Wrong Credentials!");
      }
  
      const accessToken = jwt.sign({
          id:user._id,
          isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
      },process.env.JWT_SEC,{expiresIn:"3d"}
      );
  
      const {password, ...others} = user._doc;
  
      return res.status(200).json({...others, accessToken});
  }catch(err){
      res.status(500).json(err)
  }});
```

Comment: I really appreciate your efforts, time, and knowledge but even after I replace my code with the code you suggest I'm still getting the same error

Comment: @manojMondal idk, try const OriginalPassword = await hashedPassword.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

Comment: I get 401 unauthorized in my header and get "Wrong Credintaial" responses but I don't get [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT] error also vs code suggesting that "'await' has no effect on the type of this expression.ts(80007)
"

Comment: @manojMondal I understand you, check where exactly you get Wrong Credentials, maybe you made a mistake in query(try this: findOne({ where: {username: req.body.username} }), maybe the problem is in cryptoJS but I didn’t work with it, I can’t tell

Comment: I understand I really appreciate your effort and knowledge i will check the code as you suggest